# How to convert text to numeric format in SAS

Tags: text, sas, numeric

I have a big dataset from a data warehouse where one of the varibels have been read in as a string. The variable only contains numbers and I havn't got the raw data so I can't read in the data myself.

Example:

```
Variabel
4659721685425645
1234564578978896
7894567894567894
```

The format is $20. and the informat is $19.

I want to convert it into numeric so I can join the dataset with another dataset, on the same variable, but where this variable is numeric.

I have already tried:

```
 data x_numeric;
        set x;
        format variable 20.;
 run;
```

Grateful for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A 20 digit number *cannot* be stored numerically in SAS with full precision.  SAS uses double precision floating point numbers, meaning they store the number in 8 bytes.  52 bits are used for the mantissa (the precision), 11 for the exponent, and 1 for the sign.  `2^53` is the largest number that could be stored precisely in SAS, or about 9x10^15 (any number of 15 digits, and most numbers of 16 digits).  This is true on IEEE-compliant systems (Intel-based, so Unix, Windows, etc.); IBM mainframes use 56 bits for the mantissa, so up to 2^57 can be stored precisely.

See the [SAS article on numeric precision](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lrcon/62955/HTML/default/viewer.htm#a000695157.htm) for more details.

If your number can be safely represented numerically (ie, is less than 9E16), then you can convert it using `input`.

```
var_n = input(var_c, 20.);
```

Where `20.` is the informat to read it in with (should be same width as the `format` of the character variable, not its informat).  You don't have to do this in the dataset permanently; if you're using `sql join` you can just join using `on tbl1.var = input(tbl2.var,20.)` or similar (though in a data step merge you couldn't do that).